# Cancel previous API request in Apex or LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

We have a child LWC that dispatches an event to the parent LWC with some ids that the parent will use to fetch some data from an API, filtered by those ids. These ids are selected on click and added to an array, and each click triggers the call to fetch the data.

What I would like to do is, if i click multiple ids in quick succession, i want to cancel the previous API call made to reduce the amount of calls. Something similar to [this](https://www.codingdeft.com/posts/axios-cancel-previous-request-react/).

I have done this with react/axios, but I dont know if its possible to do something similar in LWC/Apex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, we don't have any way to abort a call midflight, as we would with some frameworks. It's important to note that even if you did abort the call client-side, the server may still go through the entire operation anyways, which would be undesirable.

Instead of firing off the API call immediately, put it on a (short) timeout, perhaps around 300ms. If the user clicks another selection, you can then abort the original call and reset the timeout for 300ms again. Something like:

```
queue = []
_timeout
handleClick(event) {
  queue.push(event.target.value)
  clearTimeout(this._timeout)
  this._timeout = setTimeout(() => this.doApiCall(), 300)
}
doApiCall() {
  const queue = this.queue
  this.queue = []
  doCallout(queue).then((result) => this.dealWithResults(result))
}
```

This introduces a slight delay, but results in fewer calls. Adjust the timeout as you desire.

Comment: Yea i suspected as much, went for the option of just allowing users to select multiple ids and created a button to make the call once

Answer (score 0):

You wont have that kind of control to cancel apex or any calls once you already triggered it in salesforce UI.

The better approach is to show a spinner or disable the button one you click it and enable it again or remove the spinner once you have received a response from apex. (May it be success or error, make sure to cover both scenario and enable the button back.)

Comment: went with an approach that allowed us to select multiple ids and then just created a button to apply the filters. A few more clicks but a decent enough solution